# Extract words from a string but replace punctuation after processing

Tags: php, regex

I've been working on a little project of mine which can translate English words into generated ones inserted and taken from a database. For example the word 'potato' would become 'budfun' (much to my amusement).

First of all I attempted to translate an entire English dictionary into my alternate language however it was a slow process so I thought translating the words as they come in would be a hell of a lot easier.

The user can copy and past a paragraph into a simple html form and php would filter out the words and check to see if there is an existing entry in the database. If there is not php will then generate a word to be used and insert that into the database for later.

Currently I'm using regex to fish out words inserted by the user however I would like the output to retain punctuation after the words have been processed.

```
$words = $_POST['long'];
$words = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $words);
$words = preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i', ' ', $words);
$words = trim($words);
$pieces = explode(" ", $words);
```

Going back to the potato example, if I paste in this paragraph of information: `"However, the local importance of the potato is variable and changing rapidly. It remains an essential crop in Europe (especially eastern and central Europe), where per capita production is still the highest in the world, but the most rapid expansion over the past few decades has occurred in southern and eastern Asia. As of 2007 China led the world in potato production, and nearly a third of the world's potatoes were harvested in China and India."`

It would become: `ejijzow omr aqeri akfotwkapz ko omr budfun uo jwqixifp wka aidongfi ewmtejb pa dqnuuqs yh peuodvsuu dqte so ixespv gajhiqhxes gaoemqu wka ntebvze ixespv beqaj qze hipavw oaeiawlebu uo thvia omr koyjxuv so omr brquf lbs omr zukk hujze orijamzhi vunz omr aimr iqe vqgugfp uny eenecrod so vimeurbs wka gaoemqu dhyu ro ko yieqv ugn omr brquf so budfun oaeiawlebu wka xkpinl x vmitc ko omr brquf e fbecndix edpu agehbeano so yieqv wka olmog`

As you can see the punctuation has been dropped thanks to the filtering stated above.

Is it possible to take out the punctuation and insert it back into the translated paragraph?

Comment: Why not do this with `str_replace` and arrays of the terms and the replacements? http://php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make two arrays. One for english and one for the other language. You can fill them dynamically from your database.

Then use the [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) function.

```
$english = array("potato", "however");
$lang = array("budfun", "ejijzow");

$words = "However, the local importance of the potato is variable and changing rapidly. It remains an essential crop in Europe (especially eastern and central Europe), where per capita production is still the highest in the world, but the most rapid expansion over the past few decades has occurred in southern and eastern Asia. As of 2007 China led the world in potato production, and nearly a third of the world's potatoes were harvested in China and India.";

$translation = str_ireplace($english, $lang, $words);

echo $translation;
```

Comment: Aha! Why didn't I think of that? Thanks.